# "Не то что" или "не то чтобы"

Tags: частица

Как лучше выразиться?

Не то что поесть - поспать не смогу.
Не то чтобы поесть - поспать не смогу.

Корректна ли запятая вместо тире?

Answer (score 1):

***Не то чтобы поесть  – поспать не смогу.***

Это обычный составной союз НЕ ТО ЧТОБЫ...А, НЕ ТО ЧТОБЫ...НО.

Относится к разряду **двойных градационных союзов**, совмещает соединительное и сопоставительное значение.

Тире ставится **на места пропуска второй части двойного союза (противительного союза А)** http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=86

Примечание. Чтобы назвать составной союз фразеологизмом, нужно, как мне кажется, хорошее воображение.

Comment: "хорошее воображение" — мне тоже показалось странным, что "не то чтобы" назвали фразеологизмом. Но фразеологизм — свойственное определённому языку устойчивое словосочетание, смысл которого не определяется значением отдельно взятых слов. Оно подходит под определение. Да и в фразеологическом словаре есть: https://phraseology.academic.ru/12845/Не_то_чтобы..._а_%28но%29 На gramota.ru почему-то это не союз, а частица.

Comment: Составные союзы, вопросительно-отрицательные слова, составленные из местоимений и союзов - они тоже устойчивые и неразложимые, но их как-то не называют фразеологизмами. Вообще говоря, ссылки желательно давать на авторитетные источники, так как источников других в Сети более чем достаточно.

Comment: Согласен, но имеем правило, по которому такое называние корректно. Или не совсем корректно само правило?

Answer (score 0):

**Не то чтобы поесть — поспать не смогу.**

Не то чтобы — это фразеологизм, который в предложении работает в качестве частицы.
http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=492
https://aif.ru/society/education/ne_to_chtoby_ili_ne_to_chto_by_kak_pravilno

"Не то что" обычно употребляется в конце предложения и без сопоставления:
*Это хороший мастер, не то что некоторые.

Даже поспать не смогу, не то что поесть.*
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_491

> Корректна ли запятая вместо тире?

Да, если добавить союз "а":
*Не то чтобы поесть, а поспать не смогу.*

Именно союз "а" или тире создают сопоставление. А с одной лишь запятой это просто перечисление, и запятая равносильна союзу "и". А это далеко не то, что нужно:
*Не то чтобы поесть и поспать не смогу.*

Comment: *Не то чтобы — это фразеологизм,* Поясните, пожалуйста. По вашей ссылке это названо частицей.

Comment: По другой ссылке написано, что это фразеологизм, который в предложении работает в качестве частицы. Но ведь действительно во фразеологизме значение фразы не равняется сумме значений слов. Это здесь и имеем. Ведь фраза не может быть напрямую частицей, так как часть речи - категория слов языка, а не фраз. Но фраза может выполнять функции частицы. То есть фразу можно **условно** назвать частицей. Я так понимаю.

Comment: Источник неавторитетный. Поэтому я вас и спросил, что такое фразеологизм..

Answer (score 0):

Внутри сопоставительных союзов "*не то что…а*", "*не то чтобы…а (но)*" запятая перед "*что*" и "*чтобы*" не ставится:
*За копейку он **не то что брательника**, а самого Бога обшельмует.

В ту минуту я **не то чтобы струсил**, а немного оробел.

Брови Лизы **не то чтобы нахмурились**, а дрогнули.*
Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=161

*Не то чтобы* — употребляется перед глаголом.
*Не то что* — употребляется перед существительным.

*Поесть* — глагол.
*Не то **чтобы** поесть — поспать не смогу.*